# uwp combobox header issue with Fluent xaml theme editor

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, styles, themes

I made a custom combo box style where the border wraps around the header as well as combobox content itself. It was working fine as expected and header was showing up fine, but then I opened "Fluent xaml theme editor" (uwp theme generator from store) and left it on default and exported the theme into my "app.xaml" and now header has disappeared. Below is the link to reproduce the issue, just open the project and run it and you will see on both light and dark theme there is no header on the combobox.

Reproduce issue project: https://github.com/touseefbsb/ComboBoxThemeIssue

Min target: 1803

Target sdk: 1809/1903 (1809 shows header only in dark theme, 1903 doesn't show header in both themes)

**Output**

[image]

[image]

**Code**

**MainPage**

```
<Pivot>
        <PivotItem Header="Dropdowns">
            <PivotItem.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="dropdowns">
                    <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}">
                        <ComboBox Header="Header">
                            <ComboBoxItem>123</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>456</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>789</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </PivotItem.Resources>
            <Pivot>
                <PivotItem Header="Light" RequestedTheme="Light">
                    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dropdowns}" />
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="Dark" RequestedTheme="Dark">
                    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dropdowns}" />
                </PivotItem>
            </Pivot>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

**App.xaml**

(https://github.com/touseefbsb/ComboBoxThemeIssue/blob/master/ComboBoxThemeIssue/ComboBoxThemeIssue/App.xaml )

### Update 1

On further investigation I found out that removing "AltMediumLow" from colorpelleteResources tag fixes the issue but that very odd because that shouldn't be removed as it is part of the default generated theme by fluent theme editor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **HeaderedComboBoxStyle** in App.xaml, the style Fluent xaml theme editor generated defines only two rows for the Grid and let the Border named Background occupy two lines, so the Border coveres header. In addition, it also set the Visibility of header as **Collapsed** to hide it. But in the default style of ComboBox, it sets three rows, put the header on the first line and the Boder on the second and third line. So you can change it like the default style, for example:

App.xaml:

```
......
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        ......
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <ContentPresenter  x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}"
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            FlowDirection="{TemplateBinding FlowDirection}"
                            FontWeight="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeFontWeight}"
                            Visibility="Visible" />
         <Border x:Name="Background"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                 Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
         ......
     </Grid>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

**Update:**

Based on the HeaderedComboBoxStyle in App.xaml, the Background of Border named "Background" templateBinding Background and the Background property binds with ComboBoxBackground.

Selected the ComboBoxBackground and click F12, you will jump into **generic.xaml** file, then you can see the ComboBoxBackground bound with SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush, and actually the Color of SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush is equal to SystemAltMediumLowColor's. And in this case, the AltMediumLow from colorPelleteResources represents SystemAltMediumLowColor. So actually, the Background property binds with AltMediumLow.

When the AltMediumLow set White color in the Light theme, the Background of Border will becomes White and cover the header, so the header can't display. You can remove the Background of Border or set it as Transparent without removing the AltMediumLow.

And when you remove "AltMediumLow" from colorpelleteResources tag, the color of AltMediumLow will be set Transparent by default, so the Background of Border is also Transparent, the header will display.

```
<Border
        x:Name="Background"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
        Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" />
```

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question, I intentionally made some changes in the default style so that the background border wraps around the header as well, my aim is to merge header above combobox into the combobox itself and it was working as expected until I introduced the colorpalletes for light and dark themes, by fluent xaml theme editor app on store. hope that clarifies, if I keep header in 1st row and border and next 2 rows, it defeats the style I am trying to achieve.

Comment: as soon as I comment out "Windows10version1809:ColorPaletteResources" tag in my app.xaml the header appears again, so some color is messing up the header color I think.

Comment: Please see Update1 in the question